# How can I create a single window application using NetBeans Platform

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform

Is NetBeans platform for creating only rich client applications or we can also create single frame applications? There is a wizard for Swing Application Framework based application, but is this possible to create the same single frame application using NetBeans platform. If yes, then please guide me how can I create one. Thanks.

Comment: @Coding-Freak: [It is also a platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html).

Comment: Netbeans is also a platform for Java development !

Comment: ohho. Actually i had only known that netbeans is an ide only. thanks for the information. gained something useful. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all NetBeans is a impressive, powerful but complex platform to build java gui applications.
The main problem of all development platforms is, that there are some trade offs to be made to unleash the real power of the platform.

It is hard to tell if NetBeans Platform is an overkill for your needs. But the introduction videos and tutorials are great instruments to get a feeling of the programming model and runtime environment. They helped me a lot at the beginning.

If you have concrete questions afterwards feel free to ask.

[Netbeans Application quickstart guide](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html)